# Inverse laplace transform of $\dfrac{\alpha s}{s+\beta}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to know the inverse laplace transform of $$\dfrac{\alpha s}{s+\beta}$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are non-zero constants

I already know the result for 
$$\dfrac{\alpha }{s+\beta}$$

Which is $\alpha \exp(-\beta)$

I know there is a trick for it, but I cannot remember how to deal with the case when you have an extra $s$ on top.

Comment: $\frac {\alpha s}{s+\beta} = \alpha + \frac {-\alpha\beta}{s+\beta}$  and the inverse Laplace transform of a constant is a Dirac $\delta$ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility:
$$
\frac{s}{s + \beta} = 1 - \frac{\beta}{s + \beta}
$$

Comment: Life saver, Living Jesus